# Get XML element from ValueIterator or Array

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have results of cts.search in form of ValueIterator. The results are some XML documents. I am looking for an XPath alternative in JavaScript. I tried using `getElementByTagNameNS` but for that I need to iterate to every element. I have tried something like -

```
var arr = searchResult.toArray();
var ids = [];
for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
  ids.push(arr[j].getElementsByTagNameNS(c, 'id')[0].textContent)
}
```

Can I do it without the loop? Without iterating to each element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about removing iteration alltogether (you have an iterator as a result). Maybe in MarkLogic when you have a sequence, things will change.

This is the closest I could see to help you:
1) no cast to array
2) example of xpath in Javascript

```
var res = [];
for (var doc of cts.search("whatever")){
  res.push(doc.xpath("/path/to/whatever/text()"))  
}
```

Comment: If inefficient cast to array is kept, it is possible to eliminate loop like this: `searchResult.toArray().map(function (docFound) { return docFound.xpath('//some/xpath/path') })`.

Comment: I thought about that. but a map function still does a form of iteration since it must access every member of the array. And when you cast to an array, I believe you have extracted all of the content (because you have now accessed it). I believe ML is effecient enough that when you keep it as an iterator and use the xpath function that you are 'touching' less data overall - just the text node.  This is a fun one to ask MarkLogic about.

Comment: No. I definitely think your approach is the right solution. I was just pointing out that if the OP really wants to avoid an explicit loop in their own code, `toArray()` could be kept with the understanding that it's syntactic sugar.

Comment: One alternative to pushing onto an array would be to wrap the XPath loop within a generator function and yield the node extracted by the XPath.